# Serving an XML Django flatpage?

Tags: xml, django, django-flatpages

Is there any way to serve a flatpage with a mimetype of `text/xml`? Changing the template to one with a different file extension doesn't work, and I can't find any info in the documentation that says this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

id suggest to overwrite FlatpageFallbackMiddleware. you could set the response headers there like this:

```
#myproject/middleware.py
from django.contrib.flatpages.middleware import FlatpageFallbackMiddleware

class XmlFlatpageFallbackMiddleware(FlatpageFallbackMiddleware):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if response.status_code != 404:
            return response # No need to check for a flatpage for non-404 responses.


        response = super(XmlFlatpageFallbackMiddleware, self).process_response(request, response)
        # this depends on your settings.APPEND_SLASH
        # see django.contrib.flatpages.views.flatpage for details
        if request.path_info.endswith('.xml') or request.path_info.endswith('.xml/'): 
            response['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        return response
```

put your new middleware in **settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES** and off your xml-file goes.

additional info about how to make a custom middleware can be found [here](http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/django-creating-a-custom-middleware-component)

and here some [info about setting response headers in django](http://www.deepakkapoor.net/customize-response-headers-in-django/)